# How can I use java-specific types in Thrift service?

Tags: java, thrift

I'm writing a Thrift service which basic function is to proxy all the queries to EJB Beans. Basically service would receive a call, look up a local bean, forward a query to the bean and forward the answer back to client.

Main problem is that thrift IDL doesn't support language-specific types. For example, one of the method parameter is an object implementing interface Inamed (which extends Serializable).

How can I tell thrift that I want to import this interface from, say, "my.package.interfaces.INamed" and use it as a valid parameter/return type?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send arbitrary objects via Thrift, you can serialize them and send them as Thrift binary data and deserialize them at the other end. This would bypass type-checking though.

But Thrift is designed to be language-independent, so I don't think you can express language-specific types in the IDL.

Can you just define a Thrift struct that matches `INamed` and then use this in your other Thrift methods?

Comment: I can't define this struct - all I know about the object I receive is that it has interface INamed, I know nothing about it's class, so I don't know the fields it contains, so I can't write a struct. 

I understand the language-independency concept, but I hoped, that Thrift allowed more specific languages mechanisms, something like "void setName(1:javatype(my.package.interfaces.INamed) name)"

Comment: Another thing I think I could do is to generate the code with thrift and then modify the gen-code to adjust types and imports and stuff, but I feel that's not the right solution.